# Correlation of unpaired data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have 2 unpaired datasets: some proteins measured in a general population (several thousand of points for different ages, from 0 to 80 years old) and some physiological measures such as muscle volume / number of fibers / bones cross-section (tens of thousands of points for different ages, from 10 to 80 years old). These datapoints were obtained from different studies and different individuals so they are not paired, however since we have thousands of datapoints, we can be more or less sure in a model Muscle ~ Age or Protein ~ Age. The thing that I want is to establish Muscle ~ Protein - for illustration purposes, not for conclusions.

The hypothesis is: protein quantity changes together with the number of muscle fibers. Example of the change we observe - http://aups.org.au/Proceedings/38/69-75/ - for each dataset separately.

It is not a causation study, surely, we just want to show that strange curve shape is in concordance with the known data.

Which test should I use to test association between unpaired data? They are both connected through the same confounder - age - but I have no clue how to put it into the model.

The easiest way to show Muscle ~ Protein would be to say, like an Ancient Greek, "Look!" - visually they are the same plot, but I am afraid it won't pass a review process.

Answer (score 1):

A thought:

I don't know any specific tool to test the significance of correlation between unpaired data.

However, as Muscle~ Age and Protein~Age and you have thousands of data, if the distribution of the muscle fiber and distribution of protein within each age are normally distributed, you can calculate the means of the tissue fiber and means of the protein measure for each age. Now, you would have tissue fiber measure and protein measure as paired w.r.t age of the individuals *(not sure if this is statistically correct)*.

You can now test the correlation between these two.

Comment: Well, this is a good thought - I can generate paired data points using Muscle~Age or Protein~Age as a generative model, thanks!

Comment: I think it will be meaningful to go for partial correlation as both the variables are correlated with age.

Comment: If you don't have pairing, then partial correlation is no more possible than is correlation. I take the main idea to be that you can compare the distributions for muscle and protein, I don't see that you need to focus on means at all. If distributions are so asymmetric so that means aren't useful, there are plenty of other measures you can use. A quantile-quantile plot is a direct way of comparing distributions and doesn't depend on samples being the same size either.

Comment: QQ plot is a great idea, I'll try to work on it, thanks!